# (React Native) scrollsToTop prop not working

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, scrollview

My App has

```
return(
    <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: "#262423", flex: 1 }} scrollsToTop={true}>
         ...my ScrollView
    </ScrollView>
)
```

but when I tap on the Status Bar of my iOS device, the ScrollView doesn't scroll to the top.

Comment: according to the docs, scrollToTop is true by default https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollstotop-ios

Comment: Yes I know, but still doesn't work... :(

Comment: Can you reproduce it using [expo.dev](https://expo.dev/)?

Comment: @marcelofreires Using Expo.dev the scrollsToTop works actually, but on my real app I do have a navigation container with navigation header, might that be the cause?

Comment: This is a native function for iOS to scroll to the top of any list, you can see it works in the list of Settings. Please, try to remove the navigation header to see if it works, just to be sure it is not the problem.

Comment: Thanks but still not working with navigation header removed

Comment: Sorry about being late to answer you. I can't see what should be causing the problem. Maybe you can try animating after tapping an element at the top of the list to scroll to the top like the example from the answer below. But it is weird don't work with a tap at the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
const scrollRef = useRef();

const onPressTouch = () => {
scrollRef.current?.scrollTo({
y: 0,
animated: true,
});
}

<ScrollView ref={scrollRef}>
...your elements
</ScrollView>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressTouch}></TouchableOpacity>
```